# Button animated. When :active affects whole page

Tags: html, css

I tried to remake that 3D style button on Flat websites like the share button on G+ but when I press it, it affects the whole page by adding a `margin-top:3px` to everything. It somehow works the way I want it, but it doesn't apply only to self.

This is my code:

```
.button {
width: 100%;
background-color:#f1c40f;
color: #000000;
border: 0;
border-bottom: 3px solid #f39c12;
height: 50px;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Montserrat, Helvetica, sans serif, Arial;
font-size: 24px;
}
.button:active {
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 3px;
    height: 47px;
    outline:0;
}
```

Comment: A style for `.button:active` wouldn't apply to the entire page, however it *could* affect the page rendering depending on your styling. Do you have a fiddle or demo we can look at?

Comment: I want to add, it is in a <form>, and, looks like the same does not happen on jsfiddle.

Comment: If the same doesn't happen on jsfiddle then you need to figure out what the difference is. Something in your page that's not copied to jsfiddle is causing it.

Comment: Did you close the button tag?

Comment: I copied almost the whole code. It's just a simple project.

Comment: Figured it out. I had a display:inline-block attached to the form. Works now. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Figured the problem. I assigned a dip `display:inline-block` to the form. Works now! Watch out with that positioning. Can cause a lot of trouble!